# Can I use swank-js to complete node.js APIs in js2-mode?

Tags: node.js, emacs, elisp, slime, swank

I use swank-js in js2-mode in emacs. Can I use it to complete node.js build-in or third-party APIs such as `fs.readFile`, `fs.writeFile`, `express.use`, `async.forEach` etc. in js2-mode ? If yes, what would be the best setup for it ?

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 5):

`swank-js` support auto completion. I used it for a while with `auto-complete` mode and `ac-slime`. Here's my setup:

```
(eval-after-load 'auto-complete
  '(progn
     (add-to-list 'ac-modes 'slime-repl-mode)
     (add-to-list 'ac-modes 'js2-mode)
     (add-to-list 'ac-modes 'js-mode)
     (add-hook 'slime-mode-hook 'set-up-slime-ac)
     (add-hook 'slime-repl-mode-hook 'set-up-slime-ac)))

(eval-after-load 'slime
  '(progn
     (setq slime-protocol-version 'ignore
           slime-net-coding-system 'utf-8-unix
           slime-complete-symbol*-fancy t
           slime-complete-symbol-function 'slime-fuzzy-complete-symbol)
     (slime-setup '(slime-repl slime-js))))
```

I'm not sure about 3rd party API but I was able to auto complete my own defined modules.

Edit: Apparently it can auto complete anything require-able. If you connect to web remote, it can even complete DOM API.

[image: swank-js]

Comment: Have you been able to complete module names, or also function names inside them?

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer. I've already know that works well in the repl. But I eval the blocks in a js source file much more than using the repl. I mean: can it complete APIs in js files (as ac-sources or whatever)?

Answer (score 0):

@Ispinfx Maybe you can try the ac-js2-mode https://github.com/ScottyB/ac-js2
this mode can make auto-complete in the js files.